# Is there a word for 'encountering new ideas/perspectives'?

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to find a word that describes "meeting" a new idea. In a phrase it would be:

> Through this discussion I ____ a lot of new perspectives.

I recall a word similar to 'having a light source fall upon you'. You passively learn about something new.

Comment: Note that it's considered inappropriate to edit a question so as to invalidate any existing answers after the fact. While that isn't entirely the case here, I suspect that the current answer would not have been provided had you given the last sentence in your question from the start.

Comment: @jasonbassford My appologies, I'm new to this exchange. I will keep it in mind in the future

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word I was looking for was 'expose'

> Through this discussion I was exposed to a lot of new perspectives.

Answer (score 3):

> Through this discussion I ____ a lot of new perspectives on.

Two things to note here:

1. Many words *could* fit in that space, with varying subtleties implied.
2. Your sentence phrase is incomplete and should not end with **on**.

I'll assume that this is just the start of your sentence, and that you meant to end your phrase with an ellipsis.

The most basic words that I could think of to fit into that space and retain some of the meaning you have suggested are somewhat uninspiring—in fact you have already suggested one in your title:

- If you were made aware of some perspectives, of which you were not previously aware:

  - [encountered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encountered)
  - [discovered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discovered)
- If you worked through some perspectives, to determine what validity they held:

  - [explored](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explored)
  - [realised](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realized)

Assuming you are not writing poetry, sometimes the obvious words are the best ones to use.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question

Comment: I've upvoted this. It was a perfectly reasonable answer until the question was edited.

Comment: I've upvoted it, but I accepted the other answer as it better helped with the updated question

Answer (score 1):

From the question:

> You passively learn about something new.

With that key piece of information, I suggest [**absorb**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absorb):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : to take in (something, such as water) in a natural or gradual way
>   // a sponge *absorbs* water
>   // charcoal *absorbs* gas
>   // plant roots *absorb* water
>   **1 b** : to take in (knowledge, attitudes, etc.) : ACQUIRE, LEARN
>   // … convictions absorbed in youth …
>   — M. R. Cohen

So, in the example sentence:

> Through this discussion I *absorbed* a lot of new perspectives.

---

If in this context, *absorbed* sounds a bit odd, the alternative **acquire** could be used instead.

> Through this discussion I *acquired* a lot of new perspectives.